# "Failed to execute 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --version': exited with status 2 " to start a mesos-slave

Tags: docker, mesos

> I am trying to start a mesos cluster. I started master successfully
>   but got an error as below.

[image]

> By the way, the host OS is Centos7.4. Any idea about the solutions
>   to the problem? Below are the detailed flags in my startup file:
>   [image]

Comment: I have worked it out. It's caused by the improper version of docker. The solutions are already demonstrated clearly in order on the official website. https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.10/installing/oss/custom/system-requirements/install-docker-centos/

Comment: You can post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out. It's caused by the improper version of docker. The solutions are already demonstrated clearly in order on the official website. docs.mesosphere.com/1.10/installing/oss/custom/… – Corren Zhang Aug 30 at 14:51